# Hi,can anyone tell me how to display the table columns in a LISTBOX control in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I have to write the script to bring the columns for the selected table and display them in a list box....

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a dataobject with all its columns in it.
Use dw_1.describe("Datawindow.objects") (tabseperated String with all the objects in it),
Iterate through it and then use Listbox.AddItem()

Comment: can you tell me how to store columns in a dataobject...i dont know that since i am a beginner..\

Comment: Simply create a new dataobject, choose grid > SQL Select, now select the table, then mark all columns and save the dataobject. They should be drawn on the datawindow automatically

Comment: I got that...then how to generate the SELECT statement for the selected table depending on the columns selected and create a DataWindow dynamically and display it to the user...i already create a listbox containg table name...now i want display the selected table columns in a datawindow dynamically when user clicks a button...

Comment: Look at the function SyntaxFromSQL and dw_1.create

Comment: got that......can you tell me how to set the background logo for the window.......

Comment: you mean for the dataobject? Open it and in the properties tab go to Background and choose Picture. Programmatically you can look at File>New>Tools>Datawindow Syntax and see if there is some syntax you can use. For a normal window I would just lay a pictureobject on the window itself.

Comment: Maybe the modify method would be dw_1.modify("DataWindow.Print.FileName='myfile.jpg' "), but not sure